# Getting line of a search term - Python Script for Notepad++

Tags: python, search, notepad++, scintilla

I'm trying to automate deleting of some text on a HTML code I'm editing on Notepad++, I'm using the plugin PythonScript to do that. I only have one problem: I want to delete, for example, all the `<center>` except the first one. I thought I could use this function:

```
Editor.rereplace("search", "replace"[, flags[, startPosition[, endPosition[, maxCount]]]])
```

Since I don't want to delete the first term, I could set the `startPosition` to be one line after the one with the first term.The only problem is that I don't find any scintilla function in Python Script to locate the text I am looking for. Maybe this `research` function could help to find a solution:

```
Editor.research(search, matchFunction[, flags[, startPosition[, endPosition[, maxCount]]]])
```

But I can't find any function associated with .research that would help me.

Comment: Seems like you could write a regular expression to pass `Editor.research()` that would match everything up to and including the first newline. Editor.research() == (R(egular)E(xpression)Search) I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matches = []
def match_found(m):
    # append the match start position to the matches array
    matches.append(m.end(0))

editor.research('pattern', match_found)

matches[0]  #should now contain the index of the *end* of the first match
```

`m.end()` since you want to use the end of match as the start of the next search

Comment: Thank you again for your time RaGe, this is working just fine. :)